# Is there any GDB GUI for RAspberry Pi, Raspbian distribution

Tags: user-interface, gdb, raspberry-pi

Is there any way to install GDB GUI on Raspberry for Raspbian Distribution?, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `gdb` accepts a `-tui` argument to give you a textual terminal interface.

You can also run `gdb` under `emacs`.

And you might do [remote debugging](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html) and have the GDB GUI runs on on Linux laptop.

Perhaps [ddd](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) could be installed and/or compiled on your Raspberry Pi....